# Integrating Planck's function between 0 and infinity

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I need to find radiance, and I've found out that the integral of Planck's fuction allows me to do this. 
However, I don't understand the integration between 0 and infinity.

[image: Planck equation]

(from http://www.spectralcalc.com/blackbody/images/eq0036M.gif)

I don't understand [why they've put](http://www.spectralcalc.com/blackbody/integrate_planck.html) $2k^3T^3/ h^2c^2$ before the integral symbol, as in the first line there was nothing before it. If anyone could explain this integration for me it would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand why they've put $2k^3T^3/ h^2c^2$ before the integral
>   symbol, as in the first line there was nothing before it.

To end up with the $x$ as integration variable, which showed up before in the exponent of the exponential function, where it had the $h \nu /(kT)$ value.

Answer (score 1):

There is a ways ways smarter way to evaluate this.

$$\frac{2k^3T^3}{h^2c^2}\cdot \frac{h^3}{k^3T^3}\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{v^3\ \text{d}v}{e^{av} - 1}$$

Where I set $a = h/kT$.

Little algebra and we get

$$\alpha\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{v^3\ \text{d}v}{e^{av} - 1}$$

Where $\alpha = 2h/c^2$

Now, let's collect the exponential at the denominator

$$\alpha\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{v^3\ \text{d}v}{e^{av}(1 - e^{-av})}$$

Make use of the geometric Series

$$\frac{1}{1 - e^{-av}} = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} (e^{-av})^k$$

To get

$$\alpha\int_0^{+\infty} v^3 e^{-av} \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} e^{-avk}\ \text{d}v$$

$$\alpha\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\int_0^{+\infty} v^3 e^{-av(1 + k)}\ \text{d}v$$

Let's call $\beta = a(1+k)$ and the integral is trivial:

$$\int_0^{+\infty} v^3 e^{-\beta v}\ \text{d}v = \frac{\Gamma(4)}{\beta^4}$$

Now, $\Gamma(4) = 3! = 6$ and $b^4 = a^4(1+k)^4$ hence:

$$\alpha\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\frac{6}{a^4(1+k)^4} = \frac{6\alpha}{a^4}\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(1+k)^4}$$

The constants are $a = h/kT$, $\alpha = 2h/c^2$ hence in front of the sum we have

$$\frac{6\cdot 2h}{c^2}\frac{k^4T^4}{h^4} = \frac{12k^4T^4}{c^2h^3}$$

Finally the sum is nothing but:

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(1+k)^4} = \sum_{k = 1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(k)^4} = \zeta(4) = \frac{\pi^4}{90}$$

Hence at the end you have:

$$\frac{12k^4T^4}{c^2h^3}\frac{\pi^4}{90} = \boxed{\frac{2\pi^4}{15}\frac{k^4T^4}{c^2h^3}}$$